# Unable to set value in LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I am unable to set value to `LiveData` variable which is declared as `MutableLiveData`. The value i am trying to set is `LiveData` returned from repository.

Please find below the classes.

`Viewmodel.class`

```kotlin
    // Variable to hold list of tasks Livedata
    private val _tasks=MutableLiveData<List<TaskEntity>>()
    val tasks:LiveData<List<TaskEntity>>
        get() = _tasks

    init{
        getTasksFromDb()
    }

    private fun getTasksFromDb(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
             try {
                _tasks.value=taskRepository.getAllTasks() // Showing error here
            }catch(exception:Exception){
                Log.d(TAG,"Error "+exception.message)
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository

```kotlin
class TaskRepository (val taskDb: TaskDatabase){

    suspend fun insert(taskEntity: TaskEntity)=
        taskDb.taskDao.insert(taskEntity)

    fun update(taskEntity: TaskEntity)=
        taskDb.taskDao.update(taskEntity)

    fun delete(taskEntity: TaskEntity)=
        taskDb.taskDao.delete(taskEntity)

    fun getAllTasks():LiveData<List<TaskEntity>> =
        taskDb.taskDao.getAllTasks()
}
```

DAO

```kotlin
@Dao
interface TaskDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(taskEntity: TaskEntity)

    @Update
    fun update(taskEntity: TaskEntity)

    @Delete
    fun delete(taskEntity: TaskEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
    fun getAllTasks():LiveData<List<TaskEntity>>
}
```

Here the declared variable as well as the value I am trying to assign is also `LiveData.Still` its giving the error

```
Type mismatch: 

Required : List<Entity>, Found: LiveData<List<Entity>>
```

Can somebody help me in finding what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. It expects a List but you are trying to assign a LiveData. So you could for example just get the value from the LiveData like this:

```
_tasks.value=taskRepository.getAllTasks().value
```

That should get rid of the error, although I'm not sure if that would be the correct implementation

Comment: But I have set '_tasks' as MutableLiveData<List<Entity>> , then why is it still showing Required is  List<Entity >?

Comment: When i tried '_tasks.value=taskRepository.getAllTasks().value
' the result return in Unit .

Answer (score 0):

If working in some background thread, then you can't use setValue. You have to use postValue here with some observer.

liveData.postValue("someNewData")

Answer (score 0):

First the Livedata.value require a type of Livedata Generic

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val liveDataTemp = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
liveData.value = true //current
liveData.value = liveDataTemp //error
```

If I understand currently you want observe alltask in activity or fragment.
The following code could help you.
ViewModel

```
fun getAllTask():LiveData<List<TaskEntity>>(){
    return taskRepository.getAllTasks()
}
```

Activity or Fragment

```
viewModel.getAllTask().observer(this){
    list -> TODO()
}
```